# Is there a way to open an android app just by scanning qr code without opening any browser?

Tags: android, react-native, qr-code, deep-linking, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to add deeplinks/ applink to my android app built from react-native.

My question is that
Is there a way to open the app directly by scanning the `qr code` without opening any browser

Comment: you can visit this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android

Answer (score 0):

I think depends on what you need:)
In react-native you can access some other applications via `Linking`. For example the mail application:

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Linking.openURL('mailto:example@gmail.com')}>
     <Text>Send Email</Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

You should read the `Linking` documentation for more complex example: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking